# How to allow an Objective-C class to receive all selectors?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to intercept all messages sent to an object of type id. I don't know what class it is, but i know it conforms to a certain protocol T1.

Hence, I create an object which conforms to the same protocol but a new class type, which holds internally an object of type id, then I return this object when the original object is requested.

```
@interface Proxy 
{
    id <T1> _target;
}
...
- (void)methodA_override 
{
}
@end
```

If the user calls a method I am overriding (such as methodA_override) then everything is great.
Otherwise, i would like to forward the message to the internal object id.

The problem is, when the user calls a method I don't override, then i am hitting the following error:

```
No visible @interface for 'Proxy' declares the selector 'mehtodB'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're returning your object in place of the original object, then the code which thinks it's dealing with the original object should see it as the static type of that original object. In other words, why does the compiler "know" it's dealing with an object of your `Proxy` class at the `methodB` call site? By the way, you should be aware of the `NSProxy` root class, which is intended for this sort of thing, the `-forwardingTargetForSelector:` method, and the Objective-C forwarding machinery using `-forwardInvocation:`, etc.

Comment: You should be aware of a caveat, though: even perfect method proxying falls down if you hand your proxy to the code which created the original object. That code is entitled to access private details of the object such as instance variables without going through method calls. Since your proxy is not actually the original object and does not have those instance variables, things can blow up.

Comment: I realize that I should define my class as id<T1> and then I don't get this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ken Thomases hint, I realize that I need to return my new object as type of id and then I got no issue.
Objective-C treats id objects different than typed objects.